# How to prevent Outlook from displaying href links as plain texts in email if they are invalid?

Tags: html, email, outlook, html-templates

I have links to emails, in my email template :

```
<a href="email@email.email">email</a>
```

Even though my emails are valid, because that's what I have been asked to do, those links don't display well on Outlook, instead of having a label "email" clickable", I am having something like this on outlook web application : ( it would be the case even in web versions & mobile too I guess )

[email@email.email]Email

Real example :

```
<a
   href="email@email.email"
   style="text-decoration: none;"><span
   style="font-size: 16px; color: #055151; font-weight: 600; font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif 
   !important; text-decoration: underline; text-decoration-color: #055151;">Email</span>
</a>
```

The href is displayed as plain text on Outlook

every link has to contain https or http so it can be displayed correctly on Outlook ?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looking for redirection to mail, then it is your solution :

```
<a
   href="mailto:email@email.email"
   style="text-decoration: none;"><span
   style="font-size: 16px; color: #055151; font-weight: 600; font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif 
   !important; text-decoration: underline; text-decoration-color: #055151;">Email</span>
</a>
```